# How to set a specific refresh rate for a specific application?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming, refresh-rate, framerate

I have a game that is locked to 30 fps. I added a mod that unlocks it to the monitor refresh rate and decreases the game speed (which is locked to the refresh rate) by 50%. This way, if my desktop is running at 60Hz, I get the correct game speed, however I also get 60fps. The problem is that my monitor is running at 98Hz, thus the game is running (98/60)*original game speed. I can set it lower, to 60Hz, but then I'll need to do that, then change it back, every time I want to play that game. I'm using an RTX 2080ti and a PG27UQ monitor on Windows 10 64bit. I checked the nvidia control panel, but it doesn't allow setting the refresh rate to an explicit value on a per-application basis.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324290/batch-command-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-computer for suggestions on third-party apps, such as QRes.